# Unable to switch to TabBarController after dismissing Modal View Controller iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I want to implement login(modal) and tab Bar items(VCs) but getting stuck. I am unable to switch to tabs or the TabBarController after dismissing the modalVC. 
The Whole implementation is programmatically done. Just a blank Login VC is my root VC in main.StoryBoard.

What I want -> Dismiss LoginModal on success and switch to Tab1 of TabBarController.

What's happening? -> LoginModal being dismissed but not switching to any tab or the TabViewController or I don't know what's happening. I am attaching the Screenshots of what's happening, below. {The View after dismissing the modalVC}[image: The View after dismissing the modal.]

So,
I have a LoginViewController with a 'login' function ->

```
//LoginController.swift
func login() {
   let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
    guard let mainNavigationController = rootViewController as? MainNavigationController else { return }
    mainNavigationController.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1

    UserDefaults.standard.setIsLoggedIn(value: true)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I have created TabBarController class as follows->

```
//TabBarController.swift
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let firstViewController = HomeController() 
    firstViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .favorites, tag: 0)

    let secondViewController = EventsViewController()
    secondViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .contacts, tag: 1)

let tabBarList = [firstViewController, secondViewController, thirdViewController, fourthViewController] 
    viewControllers = tabBarList
}
```

And Finally the MainNavigationController as follows->

```
//MainNavigationController.swift
class MainNavigationController: UINavigationController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
if isLoggedIn() {
        //assume user is logged in
        let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
        guard let mainNavigationController = rootViewController as? TabBarController else { return }
        mainNavigationController.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1

    } else {
        //present LoginVC modally
        perform(#selector(showLoginController), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.01) 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're dismissing your LoginVC when there's nothing behind that controller to display.

Change your root view controller from the loginVC to your tabBarVC.  In the tabBarVC's viewWillAppear method, do the logic to check if the user it logged in or not.  If not logged in, segue (or present) the user with the LoginVC and dismiss when they log in.  If they are already logged in, skip the LoginVC segue and display your TabBarVC.